# Which Format is it ? Countdown.js

Tags: javascript

i got here in an .php file code this js code for an Countdown. Does anybody know which Date Format is it ? I dont get it..

```
                startDate   : "1932248800",
                endDate     : "2132248800",
        now     : Math.round(+new Date()/1000)
            });
```

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like Unix epoch time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC. But if so, these times are in 2031 and 2037.

Comment: Duplicate of [Convert string format Date(1528822800000) to date](/q/50980517/4642212). (Found via [answer search](/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+is%3aa+unix+epoch).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like unix timestamp in seconds:

```js
const dates = {
  startDate: "1932248800",
  endDate: "2132248800",
  now: Math.round(+new Date()/1000)
}
console.log(Object.keys(dates).map(key => 
  `${key}: ${dates[key]} = ${new Date(dates[key] * 1000)}`
).join('\n'))
```

Comment: The dates are more than 10 years in the future, my calculations are next month

Comment: @mplungjan So what? In your calculations 'now' date is next month too. Dont like now.

Answer (score 0):

Seems a time offset since if it was a unix epoch, then the dates are far in the future

```js
const dates = {
  startDate: "1932248800",
  endDate: "2132248800",
}
console.log(Object.entries(dates).map(([key,val]) => 
  `${key}:  ${new Date(+val+new Date().getTime())}`
).join('\n'))
```